# Why close the "Why does my table always disarrange in live?" question?

Tags: discussion

Why should this question be closed as off topic?

[Why does my table always disarrange in live?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/14809/120)

I have reworded the question to emphasise the Joomla related part which seems to have been drowned out by the horribly formatted table.

Answer (score 2):

I was one who voted to close this, because it is a table being generated in Joomla, but the issue is due to the inline styling being used, at a good guess, the `colspan`.

I considered that more of a Stack Overflow question which can be tagged with [html](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html), and thus voted to close.

Other may have different reasons, but that was mine

Another reason could be that the user showed no attempt to debug the issue. Maybe creating a new simplified version without any inline styling but with the same data.